# Rspec - how do i check if 3rd party js (google maps api) is loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using a gem `geocomplete_rails` (which is a places autocomplete plugin) in my rails app. This gem requires Google Maps Api. So everytime when i run my test on pages that uses this geocomplete, i get an error message (using `page.driver.console_messages`):

```
{:line_number=>54278, :message=>"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: google", :source=>"http://127.0.0.1:51330/assets/application-a820c847c6467fc2276afc746aeae8edab24cca81edfff6ea38bf8a38beb3151.js"}
```

The way i load the google maps api js is in my application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<MY_OWN_API_KEY>&libraries=places' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

So my question is there a way for me to check if the Google Maps Api js have been loaded properly in my test environment? This is so that i can find out if the error message mentioned above is caused by missing google map api or by geocomplete itself.

*Note: the geocomplete works perfectly on the development and production environment. And i am using capybara-webkit for the js testing.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do validate that it has loaded properly -- there is clearly an error in your code in your test environment that needs to be resolved.

When doing full-stack integration testing, you shouldn't be injecting any special behavior just for testing. It should all be handled by application code which would operate property in dev/production.

I'm guessing, for this particular error, you have javascript code which is trying to access the `google` object before it is loaded. I'm guessing this error is only raised on initial page load because of your use of Tubolinks.

Comment: i dont think its cause by turbolink. i've tried removing the usage of turbolinks in my app completely (dev still works normally with no issue) but this same problem still persists when running the tests. i have a feeling it's either because javascript code which is trying to access the google object before it is loaded (like you said) or the google object is not even loaded